# overpass api - requesting any node that has tag

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I was wondering if it's possible to request via overpass API "any node that has at least one tag of any kind".
The only way I see right now is to sopecify all the existing tags in a huge union request (see below), or requesting nodes without the "tag filtering" at all, and getting many nodes that have no tag at all.
I will appreciate if you know a better solution.
Thanks!

```
[out:json];
(
  node
    ["name"]
    (50.6,7.0,50.8,7.3);
  node
    ["amenity"]
    (50.6,7.0,50.8,7.3);
  AND SO ON (SPECIFY ALL THE OTHER TAGS)
);
out;
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need such a strange query?

Answer (score 8):

You can achieve this by using the following query:

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];node[~"."~"."];out meta;
```

Example: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/4Z4

Since version 0.7.54 you can also use the following approach:

```
[bbox:{{bbox}}];
node(if:count_tags() > 0);
out meta;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see this is not possible at the moment. However you can post-filter the data using [osmfilter](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter) / [osmconvert](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert).